пытаюсь изменить положение div, а он перемещается вместе с другим div
пишу свой первый сайт для личной практики, но столкнулся с проблемой.
Хотел сделать блок как витрину с кнопками-ссылками на разные соц сети, но при попытке изменить положение кнопки с помощью margin, она двигается вместе с "витриной"


#social {
  margin-top: -4px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 375px;
  height: 100px;
}

.sl {
  background-color: #696969;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
<div id="social">
  <div class="sl"></div>
</div>




Добро пожаловать на сайт, Valedol, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста со справкой, как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Для класса sl добавьте абсолютное позиционирование(position: absolute;), к примеру. Тогда элемент будет позиционироваться относительно родителя

Или можно указать display: inline-block;

Ещё один неофит обнаружил схлопывание отступов https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_box_model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Уточните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос. Не совсем понятно, что именно у вас съехало: ` 
`, оба div'a? Не видно, что именно сдвинулось ,(или я не понял, что у вас поехало). "social" — родительский элемент, поэтому под элементы тоже, как правило, перемещаются вместе с ним. Проверьте позиционирование.